# Invalid URI with Chinese characters (Java)

Tags: java, url, uri, multibyte, utf

Having trouble setting up a URL connection with Chinese characters in the URL. It works with Latin characters:

```
String xstr = "维也纳恩斯特哈佩尔球场" ;
URI uri = new URI("http","ajax.googleapis.com","/ajax/services/language/detect","v=1.0&q="+xstr,null);   
URL url = uri.toURL(); 
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream() ;
```

The getInputStream() call results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&q=???????????': Invalid query
```

Comment: Weird, I did a small JUnit test case and didn't get that exception. I'm running `java version "1.6.0_20" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.4) (6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)` Are you sure your .java file encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: Pretty sure--the characters go into the datastore as expected as long as that step is passed. In googling around I found an Oracle page http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html that states as acceptable "...the Unicode characters that are not in the US-ASCII character set, are not control characters (according to the Character.isISOControl method), and are not space characters (according to the Character.isSpaceChar method)  (Deviation from RFC 2396, which is limited to US-ASCII)." So maybe it depends on the implementation? Mine is Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that `URI.toURL()` doesn't percent-encode non-ASCII characters. Use the following instead:

```
URL url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
```

Comment: Hey, I go out for a few minute to shovel the driveway and I come back and my question is answered. I love this site...

Comment: One can also achieve the same result with: `String xstr = URLEncoder.encode("维也纳恩斯特哈佩尔球场", "utf-8"); URL url = new URL("http","ajax.googleapis.com","/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&q="+xstr);`.

Comment: On further testing, turn out that URLEncoder works better than toASCIIString for this purpose. The latter fails when the string includes square brackets, as it leaves those alone & they are not legal in a URL.

Comment: @hleinone Why we use `utf-8`? What's the standard? Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

axtavt's answer above saved me from insanity, thanks! Just one comment (I could not figure out how to comment below the answer:)

If you start with a URL, you need to encode quotes before you build the URI:

```
String s = "your_url?with=\"quotes\"";
URI su = new URI (s.replaceAll("\"", "%22");
URL ur = new URL( su.toASCIIString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the "UTF-8" charset. Have a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766361/how-to-save-chinese-characters-to-file-with-java) to learn more and also this [chinese in java](http://www.chinesecomputing.com/programming/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (see section 2.4), non-US-ASCII characters aren't valid in a URI. You must encode them.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading image url with special characters. Below snippet show how to read image property from URL with special characters.

1. replace  and  with actual IP address and port number with your actual port number.
2. In case If you are working with domain, you can replace : with the domain name.
3. Replace the <file_path> with your file path.

   ```
    try {
        String fileName = "pexels-martin-péchy-1866149%20(1).jpg";
        URI uri = new URI("http://<IP>:<port>/<file_path>/" + fileName);
        URL url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();


        System.out.println("Image downloaded successfully!: " + url.toString()+" height: "+height);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```