# Convert Arabic and Chinese characters to their ASCII values

Tags: android, string, asciiencoding

I'm trying to convert some Arabic and Chinese characters to their ASCII values to pass into a URL in Android but I really don't have any idea how to get started. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: They don't have ASCII values.  They don't even have ISO 8859/1 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a SO question that is probably close to what you are looking for

[Invalid URI with Chinese characters (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831301/invalid-uri-with-chinese-characters-java)