# Getting FileNotFoundException even though file is there in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to fetch an image from a link, here is what i do:

```
public class FetchImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HATA", "THERE is an error", e);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    return LoadImageFromWeb(url);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {

}
```

}

For the url http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/INDIRIM/ao/Pril_TR_MAX_750ml_Lemon_189227_print_1772H_1772W-500x500.png i succesfully get the image. However, when i try the url  http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/cay/Ncapkırmızı-500x500.jpg it gives me a filenotfoundexception. Here is the stactrace:

```
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015): THERE is an error
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015): java.io.FileNotFoundException:     http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/cay/Ncapkırmızı-500x500.jpg
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.net.URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler.getContent(URLConnection.java:1018)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:199)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at com.example.barcodescanner.FetchImage.LoadImageFromWeb(FetchImage.java:18)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at com.example.barcodescanner.FetchImage.doInBackground(FetchImage.java:30)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at com.example.barcodescanner.FetchImage.doInBackground(FetchImage.java:1)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-11 18:22:15.475: E/HATA(16015):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It is really weird. Can it be because of some Turkish characters in the link such as "ı", not "i" ? If that is so, how can i fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I just realized another thing, when i open the followink link in the browser,

http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot 7-500x500.jpg

I see that the link changes and becomes :

http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/DUZELTME/dvm/screenshot%207-500x500.jpg

So, why is that happening and why cannot i use the first link while trying to fetch the image?

Comment: internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @Selvin yes, also i can actually fetch some images from other links, but some links do not work, weird

Comment: You should encode your links with url encode, not sure how it is done for android. Your nescafe link should be http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/cay/Ncapk%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1-500x500.jpg for example

edit: last part is "Ncapk%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1-500x500.jpg", stackoverflow crops long links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the "ı" Turkish character: if you look your answer, you will see that Stackoverflow does not recognize automatically the url that is giving you problems.

With Firefox i can access to your url, but when i check the url with the developers tools, the url is http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/image/cache/data/cay/Ncapk%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1-500x500.jpg
Take note that the non ASCII characters are escaped.

Edit 1:

For access to an url with nons ascii characters, you need to encode the part of the url with the special characters before make the request: [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Comment: thanks, so isn't there any way to fetch the image from that url?

Comment: There are routines in android to convert your url. See the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the answer here:

[Invalid URI with Chinese characters (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831301/invalid-uri-with-chinese-characters-java)