# What character set should be used for URL encoding?

Tags: java, urlencode

I need to encode a URL component. The URL component can contain special character like "?,#,=" and also characters of Chinese language.

Which of the character sets should I use: UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32? and why?

Comment: [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is something completely different than character encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you mean percent encoding here.

[RFC 3986, section 2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.5) is pretty clear about this (emphasis mine):

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual
> data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS],
> the data **should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
> character encoding [STD63]**; then only those octets that do not
> correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-
> encoded.  For example, the character A would be represented as "A",
> the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE would be represented
> as "%C3%80", and the character KATAKANA LETTER A would be represented
> as "%E3%82%A2".

Therefore, this should be UTF-8.

Also, beware of `URLEncoder.encode()`; while the recommendation for it is repeatedly repeated, the fact is that it is not suitable for URI encoding; quoting the javadoc of the class itself:

> This class contains static methods for converting a String **to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format**

which *is not* what URI encoding uses. (in case you are wondering, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is what is used in HTTP POST data) What you want to use is a URI template instead. See for instance [here](https://github.com/fge/uri-template).

Answer (score 2):

A reference from a HTML point of view.

The HTML4 specification, section [Non-ASCII characters in URI attribute values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.1), states (my emphasis):

> We recommend that user agents adopt the following convention for
>   handling non-ASCII characters in such cases:
>
> 1. Represent each character in **UTF-8** (see [RFC2279]) as one or more bytes.
> 2. Escape these bytes with the URI escaping mechanism (i.e., by converting each byte to %HH, where HH is the hexadecimal notation of
>      the byte value).

Similar, in HTML5 specification, the [Selecting a form submission encoding section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#selecting-a-form-submission-encoding), basically says that **UTF-8** should be used if no `accept-charset` attribute is specified.

On the other hand, I found nothing that states UTF-8 *must* be used. **Some older software use iso-8859-1** in particular. For example, Apache Tomcat before version 8 has iso-8859-1 as default value for its `URIEncoding` setting.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 (Unicode) is the default character encoding in HTML5, as it encompasses almost all symbols/characters.

Answer (score 0):

Go for UTF-8, also you can achieve the same thing by 
[URLEncoder.encode(string, encoding)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

In addition, you can refer
[This blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831301/invalid-uri-with-chinese-characters-java), It tried to encode some Chinese characters like '维也纳恩斯特哈佩尔球场'

Answer (score -2):

Encode your URL to escape special characters. There are several websites that can do this for you. 
E.g. http://www.url-encode-decode.com/