# QueryParam decode my url encoded with cp1252

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, encoding, urlencode

I have a get request with this param in the url (**encoded in cp1252**):

```
?c=es&t=a%20coru%F1a
```

I have a Spring Boot service with a QueryParam that automatically converts to:

```
a coru�a
```

The %20 are replaced by spaces and the %F1 are replace by �

If I try to encode again:

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode(t, "Windows-1252");
```

This is the final result (%3F instead %F1)

```
a+coru%3Fa
```

What I need is the QueryParam doesn't decode the url, I only want that string as a I send it.

If I try with POST request and x-www-form-urlencoded everything works fine (obviously), but I need GET request.

Comment: Did you try re-encoding (double encoding) that string and sending? like `a%2520coru%25F1a`

Comment: Hi, I can't modify the string I send (actually, others send)

Comment: All URL parameters should be encoded and decoded with `UTF-8` See [What charsets should be used for url encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276432/what-charsets-should-be-used-for-url-encoding)   The client that is making the get request is doing it wrong.  This isn't your problem, the client needs to be modified.

Comment: yes, i know, but it's pretty difficult to change that, thx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did it at the end:

I've changed @RequestParam by:

```
HttpServletRequest request
```

And then:

```
request.getQueryString()
```

And I can get the values from the query url in the same format.

Probably it's not the best option, but it works!

Thanks.