# Can not show chinese when export CSV file from android device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use this jar file to create a CSV file on my android project.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/opencsv/downloads

I can create it and mail it with an attachment by using `Intent`, but when i open the csv file chinese is not right(just like the photo)
[image]

The Comment content correct word should be `今天好棒棒1`
[image]

I try two solutions, the first is change the string format when writing row.

Here is my Excel class, i change my comment data `listdata.get(9)` and save it with `formatComment` , its no working.

```
public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private List<Contact> contactList;

    public ExportDatabaseCSVTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "Exporting database...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        String path = mContext.getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir().getPath() + File.separator + "sugar";
        File exportDir = new File(path);
        //File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
        if (!exportDir.exists()) {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        } else {
            exportDir.delete();
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "MyDailySugar.csv");
        try {

            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            //data
            db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
            //my data
            contactList = db.sortingDate();
            //Headers
            String arrStr1[] = {"Date", "Before Morning", "After Morning",
                    "Before Noon", "After Noon",
                    "Before Night", "After Night",
                    "Before Exercise", "After Exercise", "Comment"};

            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr1);

            for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getDate());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getBeforeMorning());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getAfterMorning());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getBeforeNoon());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getAfterNoon());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getBeforeNight());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getAfterNight());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getBeforeExercise());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getAfterExercise());
                listdata.add(contactList.get(i).getComment());
                String formatComment = listdata.get(9);
                formatComment = new String(formatComment.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
                System.out.println("formatComment=>" + formatComment);
                String arrStr[] = {listdata.get(0), listdata.get(1), listdata.get(2),
                        listdata.get(3), listdata.get(4),
                        listdata.get(5), listdata.get(6),
                        listdata.get(7), listdata.get(8), formatComment};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
            }
            csvWrite.close();
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            return "";
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String success) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (success.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Export successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Export failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I try another way like this:

```
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
    out.write(0xFEFF);
    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(out, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
```

Its no working...

and my second solution is try to change the database to uft8

Here is my create database class, i try to add `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` , it show syntax error near DEFAULT , i don't know why...

```
//Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    System.out.println("table is here");
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BMORNING + " TEXT," + KEY_AMORNING + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BNOON + " TEXT," + KEY_ANOON + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BNIGHT + " TEXT," + KEY_ANIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BEXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," + KEY_AEXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',"
            + KEY_COMMENT + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''" +
            ")" + " DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}
```

I have no idea that is there another solution i can try.
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766361/how-to-save-chinese-characters-to-file-with-java Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link , i try to use `Charset
                    .forName("UTF-8")` , its still no working :(

Comment: I just tried the suggestion by the link and it works to save Chinese in file. I use Writer, not CSVWriter, and Chinese words directly from program, not read from database. On the other hand, the Chinese words are viewed correctly only under Windows (I tried Notepad and Excel), not Android.

Comment: Happy to heard you told me that, i try to change use Java POI that is more easier to print Chinese words. Thanks Mok.